# Android How to keep a method running?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, loops, methods

I was trying to put accelerator sensor's data value of x,y,z axis's on textview views. I have managed to read realtime values when I put setTextview function in the `SensorEventListener's` (interface) callback method which is named `onSensorChanged`.

As far as I can tell when the sensor's value gets updated the callback method sends the values in an object and by implementing this interface we can receive these values. Somehow Sensor Manager (the class hosting the listener and event generating method) continuously reads sensor values therefore our implemented method can put values to textview via settext method.

What I don't understand how Sensor Manager's method keeps working? I have tried to write a loop  in method which is invoked by a button but I think these loops turned out to be infinite loops and Android gave error and stopped the app. Loop methods do not seem to be patient they are trying to reach a return or break ASAP. Should I use a Thread? or is there way to create a method that keeps running?

```
     @Override
        public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
            if (event.sensor.getType() != Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER)
                return;

            mSensorX = event.values[0];
            mSensorY = event.values[1];
            mSensorZ = event.values[2];
            mSensorTimeStamp = event.timestamp;
            mCpuTimeStamp = System.nanoTime();

//            TextView mTextView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
//          mTextView1.setText("X ekseninde " + mSensorX + " deger");
//          
//          TextView mTextView2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
//          mTextView2.setText("Y ekseninde " + mSensorY + " deger");
//          
//          TextView mTextView3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
//          mTextView3.setText("Z ekseninde " + mSensorZ + " deger");
//          
//          TextView mTextView4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
//          mTextView4.setText("Sensor TimeStamp  " + mSensorTimeStamp + " time");
//          
//          TextView mTextView5 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView5);
//          mTextView5.setText("Cpu TimeStamp " + mCpuTimeStamp + " time");

        }

        public void startSimulation(View v) {
            mLever = true;
            mSimulator.startSimulation1(mLever);

        }

        public void stopSimulation (View v) {
            mLever = false;
            mSimulator.stopSimulation2();
        }

        class Simulator {



        public boolean startSimulation1(boolean x) {

            mLever = x;
            if (mLever == true) {

            TextView mTextView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            mTextView1.setText("X ekseninde " + mSensorX + " deger");

            TextView mTextView2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            mTextView2.setText("Y ekseninde " + mSensorY + " deger");

            TextView mTextView3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
            mTextView3.setText("Z ekseninde " + mSensorZ + " deger");

            TextView mTextView4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
            mTextView4.setText("Sensor TimeStamp  " + mSensorTimeStamp + " time");

            TextView mTextView5 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView5);
            mTextView5.setText("Cpu TimeStamp " + mCpuTimeStamp + " time");

            return startSimulation1(true);

            }
            else
            return false;

                }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason the app stopped previously was because you were likely going into an infinite loop on the main thread.
Try starting a new thread and running your loop in there. Do bear in mind that any updates to the UI (`setText`) will need to be done on the UI thread.
This can be achieved by sending `runnables` to the `handler` of the UI Thread like this:

```
Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
handler.post(new Runnable(){
    public void run(){
        mTextView5.setText("Cpu TimeStamp " + mCpuTimeStamp + " time");
    }
});
```